# Проблема при парсинге json при переходе на другой язык (поддомен)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, json, google-maps-api, javascript

Здравствуйте. Тяну json для гугл карт с использованием geoxml3 вот таким образом:

```
 $.getJSON( 'http://lovelike.in.ua/wp-content/themes/point/js/markers.json', function(data) { 
            $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
                $('#map-canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                    'bounds' : true,
                    'region': [marker.region],
                    'district': [marker.district],
                    'selo': [marker.selo],
                    'url': marker.url,
                    'icon': 'http://lovelike.in.ua/wp-content/themes/point/images/Marker-fond.png'
                }) ......
Когда меняю язык сайта(en.site.ru), хром выводит ошибку и json не грузится.
Вот ошибка
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://site.ru/markers.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://en.site.ru' is therefore not allowed access. 
Немного порывшись в инете, ничего не понял....((( Помогите!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Может, кому поможет. В

```
$.getJSON( 'http://lovelike.in.ua/wp-content/themes/point/js/markers.json', function(data) {
```

указал такой путь:

```
wp-content/themes/point/js/markers.json.
```

Answer (score 0):

Это значит, что хочешь вытянуть данные не со своего сервера. Попробуй между последними `"})"` написать `"jsonp"`, то есть последная пара должна иметь вид `}, "jsonp");`.

Comment: Не помогло, ошибок нет, но маркеры не грузятся всё равно.

Comment: Я знаю, как сделать с помощью CURL, через JS надо смотреть, как сделать.

Comment: Есть где что почитать? Можете посоветовать?

Comment: А если после `$.getJSON( 'http://lovelike.in.ua/wp-content/themes/point/js/markers.json', function(data) {`  написать `console.log(data);`, что выведет?

Comment: Убрал весь код. Оставил инициализацию карты и гетджсон, добавил консоль.лог и... ничего.